# Match partial string from list with field

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to check if a field contains a value from a list using Kusto in Log analytics/Sentinel in Azure.

The list contains top level domains but I only want matches for subdomains of these top levels domains. The list value example.com should match values such as forum.example.com or api.example.com.

I got the following code but it does exact matches only.

```
let domains = dynamic(["example.com", "amazon.com", "microsoft.com", "google.com"]);
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where RemoteUrl in~ (domains)
| project TimeGenerated, DeviceName, InitiatingProcessAccountUpn, RemoteUrl
```

I tried with endswith, but couldn't get that to work with the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that [has_any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-anyoperator) would work for you:

```
let domains = dynamic(["example.com", "amazon.com", "microsoft.com", "google.com"]);
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where RemoteUrl has_any(domains)
| project TimeGenerated, DeviceName, InitiatingProcessAccountUpn, RemoteUrl
```

Note that you can also use the [has_any_index()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-any-index-function) to get which item in the array was matched

Comment: While this approach will match what you want, it will also match what you do NOT want. For example, it will allow things like "example.com.hacker.com" and "hacker.com/example.com". For an alternative approach, see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

In order to correctly match URLs with a list of domains, you need to build a regex from these domains, and then use the [`matches regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/regex-operator) operator.

Make sure you build the regex correctly, in order not to allow these:

- example.com.hacker.com
- hackerexample.com
- hacker.com/example.com
- Etc...